# Why is the getValue of LiveData<Long> Nullable?

Tags: kotlin

The Code A is based https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/LiveDataSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/livedatabuilder/LiveDataViewModel.kt

I modified some code.

I think that `emit(timeStampToTime(currentTime.value))` will be correct, but the system report error, so I have to use `emit(timeStampToTime(currentTime.value?:0))`

1:  I'm very strange that why `val currentTime` isn't Nullable and `currentTime.value` is Nullable .

2:  Why does the original code use `liveData { emit(timeStampToTime(it)) }` instead of `liveData { emit(timeStampToTime(it?:0)) }`

**Code A**

```
class LiveDataViewModel(
    private val dataSource: DataSource
) : ViewModel() {

    val currentTime = dataSource.getCurrentTime()

    val currentTimeTransformed: LiveData<String> = liveData {
       //emit(timeStampToTime(currentTime.value))  // It will cause error     
       emit(timeStampToTime(currentTime.value?:0))

    }


    //Original Code
    // Coroutines inside a transformation
    //  val currentTimeTransformed = currentTime.switchMap {
    //   timeStampToTime is a suspend function so we need to call it from a coroutine.
    //    liveData { emit(timeStampToTime(it)) }
    // }

    private suspend fun timeStampToTime(timestamp: Long): String {
        delay(500)  // Simulate long operation
        val date = Date(timestamp)
        return date.toString()
    }

}



class DefaultDataSource(private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher) : DataSource {

    override fun getCurrentTime(): LiveData<Long> =
        liveData {
            while (true) {
                emit(System.currentTimeMillis())
                delay(1000)
            }
        }
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nullable because there is a constructor

> LiveData()
>
> Creates a LiveData with no value assigned to it.

and calling e.g.

```
val data: LiveData<Long> = LiveData()
data.value
```

will return `null`.

Or to consider your code:

```
liveData {
    while (true) {
        emit(System.currentTimeMillis())
        delay(1000)
    }
}
```

You `emit` a value immediately, but if you change the order

```
liveData {
    while (true) {
        delay(1000)
        emit(System.currentTimeMillis())
    }
}
```

then there is no value emitted during the first second and calling `currentTime.value` will return `null`.

(Note: is it intentional that you create a new `LiveData` on every `currentTime` access?)